# Interactive Trivia Game - how do i make the game timing the same for every playerw

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Im looking to sync my php, js, mysql trivia game to make a countdown timer so the game starts for every player at the same time. The questions will be displayed on a Tv when the trivia match starts and the multiple choice answers will be loaded on the players phones and each player will have the same amount of time to answer each question on their phones. My problem is that im not sure how to go about syncing the game timing for every player so that countdown timer for each question is the same for every player and its not dependent on page load. Ultimately every question and set of multiple choice answers should be displayed to each player at same time. If someone can point me in the right direction to set something like this up, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Look into websockets or possibly server-sent events. You should be *pushing* the updates to the clients, rather than pulling/requesting (page load).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for real time communication for the web which is usually delivered using Websockets. If you feel like hosting your own server take a look at [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) otherwise look into services like [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) or [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/).